# How to avoid page breaks before a block in XSL-FO?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am converting HTML with paragraphs followed by blockquotes into FO using XSL.

How can I avoid page breaks between the paragraphs and the blockquote that follows?

Page breaks following the blockquotes are fine.

Example:

```
<p> Some paragraph..</p>
<blockquote>My reference</blockquote>
<p> Another paragraph..</p>
<blockquote>My reference</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need what is called a [keep condition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#keepbreak) between the block generated by a normal `p` and the one generated by a `blockquote`.

In particular, as `p` is a general-purpose tag, I think the best option is to use the attribute `keep-with-previous.within-page="always"` in the `fo:block` generated for the `blockquote` HTML element.

If you are using XSLT to create the XSL-FO output, you need something like this (you may need to adjust namespaces):

```
<xsl:template match="blockquote">
    <fo:block keep-with-previous.within-page="always" ...other attributes...>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way would be to wrap the elements you want to keep together with a `fo:block`, and add a `keep-with-next.within-page="always"` attribute, as shown [here](http://www.antennahouse.com/support/qa/QA/2005061001.html):

```
<fo:block keep-with-next.within-page="always">
    ... content of p and blockquote elements
</fo:block>
```